# Fast taps (clicks) on RecyclerView opens multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have implemented onClick listener to my ViewHolder for my RecyclerView

But when I perform very fast double taps or mouse clicks, it performs the task (opens a seperate fragment in this case) twice or three times.

here is my code

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tvTitle, tvDescription;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tvDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.onClick(FRAGMENT_VIEW, getAdapterPosition()); // open FRAGMENT_VIEW
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to prevent such behaviour?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can modify it like this.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
        View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tvTitle, tvDescription;
    private long mLastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private static final long CLICK_TIME_INTERVAL = 300;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tvDescription = (TextView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - mLastClickTime < CLICK_TIME_INTERVAL) {
            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = now;
        mListener.onClick(FRAGMENT_VIEW, getAdapterPosition()); // open
                                                                // FRAGMENT_VIEW
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is good but it only solves the issue for the case on which the same item is touched. What I mean is that if the user touches item1 and immediately touches item2 then two fragments will open. At least, this is happening to me.

Comment: @Roger What solution did you implement? I am thinking to use debounce or throttleFirst from rxJava but that solves the problem on specific views.

Comment: @Roger move the click logic into the adapter to handle the click on every item of your list: Pass an interface to the viewHolder and call it on every click listener. In the adapter implement interface and prevent multiple click with the CLICK_TIME_INTERVAL

Answer (score 26):

The most straightforward approach here would be using `setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(false)` in your `RecyclerView`.

By default, this is set to true in `RecyclerView`, allowing multiple touches to be processed.

When set to false, this `ViewGroup` method prevents the `RecyclerView` children to receive the multiple clicks, only processing the first one.

See more about this [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152859).

Comment: short and sweet solution.

Comment: This isn't true, and the internal docs confirm it:     

 * @param split <code>true</code> to allow MotionEvents to be split and dispatched to multiple
     *              child views. <code>false</code> to only allow one child view to be the target of
     *              any MotionEvent received by this ViewGroup.

in simple terms, setting this only blocks multiple touch events from being processed by different children, but a child can still receive many touch events. (or even more simply put, click a -> b not possible, but a -> a double tap is still possible)

Comment: awesome short and sweet

Comment: setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(false) Wokrs like charm :)

Comment: @joao2fast4u , but it prevents callback for more than 1 item, not multiple click on the same item...I think there might be something else of debouncing

Answer (score 7):

This is a very annoying behavior. I have to use an extra flag to prevent this in my work.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView tvTitle, tvDescription;
private boolean clicked;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setClickable(true);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    tvDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(clicked){
        return;
    }
    clicked = true;
    v.postDelay(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(View v){
              clicked = false;
          }
    },500);
    mListener.onClick(FRAGMENT_VIEW, getAdapterPosition()); // open FRAGMENT_VIEW
}
}
```

Comment: **thanks**, ur concept is right and it works, but there must be some proper way of handling it, i just don't know it yet, thank again anyway.

Comment: use --> new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {...} instead of v.postDelay(new Runnable(){...}

Comment: Small change
 if(clicked){
                    return;
                }
                clicked = true;
                v.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        clicked = false;
                    }
                },500);

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach, slower devices may not be able to finish the click event in a half second depending on what happens in the click event, which is going to result in the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Kotlin you can go with this based on Money's answer

```
class CodeThrottle {
    companion object {
        const val MIN_INTERVAL = 300
    }
    private var lastEventTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    fun throttle(code: () -> Unit) {
        val eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (eventTime - lastEventTime > MIN_INTERVAL) {
            lastEventTime = eventTime
            code()
        }
    }
}
```

Create this object in your view holder

```
    private val codeThrottle = CodeThrottle()
```

Then do the following in your bind

```
name.setOnClickListener { codeThrottle.throttle { listener.onCustomerClicked(customer, false) } }
```

Putting whatever code you need called in place of

```
listener.onCustomerClicked(customer, false)
```

Answer (score 3):

Add below attributes in your theme

```
<item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
<item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
```

This will prevent multiple tap at same time.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a boolean variable in Adapter

```
boolean canStart = true;
```

- Make OnClickListener like

```
ViewHolder.dataText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (canStart) {
            canStart = false; // do canStart false 
            // Whatever you want to do and not have run twice due to double tap
        }
    }
}
```

- Add setCanStart method in Adapter class:

```
public void setCanStart(boolean can){
    canStart = can;
}
```

- At last in the fragment's or Activity's ( Where the adapter is assigned to the recyclerview ) add this onResume()

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.setCanStart(true);
    }
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: This won't work because the dispatchTouchEvent queues up the next click handler and runs it well before most systems get the chance to set the boolean in their click handlers to true, so this isn't going to be a viable option in many or even most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late and the answer has already been given, but I found that this similar issue for my case was due to a third party library Material Ripple Layout. By default it enables a delay call to onClick and allows for multiple request to be made to onClick so when the animation finishes all those clicks get registered at once and opens multiple dialogs.

this setting cancels the delay and fixed the problem for me in my case.

```
app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast taps (clicks) on RecyclerView can cause two situations-

1. A single item of RecyclerView clicked multiple times.
   This can cause the destination fragment to be created multiple times thereby making a single fragment stack up multiple times, disrupting the user's smooth experience.
2. Multiple items of the RecyclerView being clicked at a time.
   This can cause the undesired behavior of the app. (Opening multiple fragments again.)

Both situations should be handled for a proper app running experience.
To prevent 1st situation you can use the logic that within a definite interval of time if the item is clicked more than once then it should not go for creating a new fragment.
Here is the code below-

```
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     //Suppose your item is a CardView
     private CardView cardView;
      private static final long TIME_INTERVAL_GAP=500;
      private long lastTimeClicked=System.currentTimeMillis();
      public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
        cardView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        
          cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long now=System.currentTimeMillis();
            //check if cardView is clicked again within the time interval gap
            if(now-lastTimeClicked<TIME_INTERVAL_GAP)
                return;       //no action to perform if it is within the interval gap.
            mLastClickTime=now;
            //... Here your code to open a new fragment  
             }
         });
         
         }

     
      }
```

Solution for 2nd scenario-
RecyclerView has a method setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(boolean split)

The documentation says-

Enable or disable the splitting of MotionEvents to multiple children during touch event dispatch. This behavior is enabled by default for applications that target an
SDK version of HONEYCOMB or newer.

When this option is enabled MotionEvents may be split and dispatched to different child views depending on where each pointer initially went down. This allows for user interactions such as scrolling two panes of content independently, chording of buttons and performing independent gestures on different pieces of content. Split set to true to allow MotionEvents to be split and dispatched to multiple child views. and set it to false to only allow one child view to be the target of.

So in your code just add a line of code-

```
     recyclerView.setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(false);
```

These will surely solve the problem caused due to fast taps on the RecyclerView and prevent your app to stack up the same fragment unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I repurposed the [DebouncingOnClickListener](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife-runtime/src/main/java/butterknife/internal/DebouncingOnClickListener.java) from Butterknife to debounce clicks within a specified time, in addition to preventing clicks on multiple views.

To use, extend it and implement `doOnClick`.

**DebouncingOnClickListener.kt**

```
import android.view.View

/**
 * A [click listener][View.OnClickListener] that debounces multiple clicks posted in the
 * same frame and within a time frame. A click on one view disables all view for that frame and time
 * span.
 */
abstract class DebouncingOnClickListener : View.OnClickListener {

    final override fun onClick(v: View) {
        if (enabled && debounced) {
            enabled = false
            lastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            v.post(ENABLE_AGAIN)
            doClick(v)
        }
    }

    abstract fun doClick(v: View)

    companion object {
        private const val DEBOUNCE_TIME_MS: Long = 1000

        private var lastClickTime = 0L // initially zero so first click isn't debounced

        internal var enabled = true
        internal val debounced: Boolean
            get() = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClickTime > DEBOUNCE_TIME_MS

        private val ENABLE_AGAIN = { enabled = true }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make class implementing View.OnClickListener

```
public class DoubleClickHelper implements View.OnClickListener {

    private long mLastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private static final long CLICK_TIME_INTERVAL = 300;
    private Callback callback;

    public DoubleClickHelper(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - mLastClickTime < CLICK_TIME_INTERVAL) {
            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = now;
        callback.handleClick();
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void handleClick();
    }
}
```

And than use it like:

```
ivProduct.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickHelper(() -> listener.onProductInfoClick(wItem)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late but it can work for other people:

```
recyclerAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = ....
            if(id == 1){
                view.setClickable(false); //add this
                Intent a = new Intent...
                startActivity(a);

            }else if(id == 2){
                view.setClickable(false);
                Intent b = ...
                startActivity(b);
            }
        }
    });
```

Fragment - onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).invalidateOptionsMenu();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter); //add this
}
```

It works for me, i don't know if it's correct.

Comment: This is very case specific solution and there are better solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent multiple clicks, you can use an `AtomicBoolean` as a flag to keep track of whether a click is in progress. Before executing the click action, check the flag, and return early if a click is already in progress.

Otherwise, set the flag to `true`, execute the click action, and reset the flag back to `false` when the action is complete.

Here's a generic solution for preventing multiple clicks on a view item using a function property as a click listener delegate and a modified `onViewAttachedToWindow` method:

```kotlin
class YourAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    // Click Listener Delegate
    var onItemClickListener: ((item: Any, itemView: View) -> Unit)? = null

    private val clickInProgress = AtomicBoolean(false)

    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { view ->
            // Check if click is in progress
            if (clickInProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                val position = holder.adapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    val item = getItem(position) // Replace with your method to get the item based on the position
                    onItemClickListener?.invoke(item, view)
                    clickInProgress.set(false) // Reset the clickInProgress state after the action is complete
                } else {
                    clickInProgress.set(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null)
    }

    // Implement the rest of your adapter methods here
}
```

In this solution, we have created an `onItemClickListener` that takes an `item` and a `view` as its parameters. We use the adapter position to get the corresponding item using the `getItem()` function. You should replace the `getItem()` call with the appropriate method for your adapter to get the item based on the position.

To use this solution, simply set the `onItemClickListener` property in your adapter with a lambda function that handles the click events.

```kotlin
yourAdapter.onItemClickListener = { item, itemView ->
    // Handle the click event here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting this inside my recyclerview

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

But that doesn't solve the issue if you double tap on the item.

Since I'm adding my fragments to backstack I implemented it like this:

```
private void addFragmentToBackstack(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()) {
            // If there are pending transactions, wait for them to be executed
            return;
        }
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            // Fragment already exists in the back stack, do nothing
            return;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(tag)
                .commit();
    }
```

And if you are not adding a Fragment but showing an Activity when pressing on recyclerview item, then you can solve that by adding launchMode inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Just my two cents, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but I was using Kotlin and solved it by using Throttling Class with debounce like this:

```
    class ThrottleFirst(
    private val interval: Long = 300
){
    private var debounceJob: Job? = null

    fun debounce(scope: CoroutineScope, operation: suspend ()->Unit){
        if (debounceJob == null) {
            debounceJob = scope.launch {
                operation()
                delay(interval)
                debounceJob = null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then calling my adapter click listener like this:

```
wallpaperAdapter = WallpaperAdapter(requireContext()){wallpaper->
            throttleFirst.debounce(lifecycleScope){
                bottomSheet = DownloadBottomSheet(wallpaper)
                bottomSheet?.dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                getGoogleInterstitialAd {
                    if (StorageHelper.backgroundExist(wallpaper.id, context)) {
                        startSetActivity(wallpaper)
                    } else {
                        bottomSheet?.show(
                            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
                            DownloadBottomSheet.TAG
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My Adapter class:

```
class WallpaperAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val listener: (Wallpaper) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WallpaperAdapter.WallpaperViewHolder>(
)
```

Comment: Please remove the code from the answer that isn't useful for the question and explain why you think that he should rather use a coroutine instead of a simple timestamp check.

Comment: Because I was having the same issue and solved it using the above method. I thought it would help someone who is using Kotlin. And Now, most of the developers use Kotlin.